# How to get last access/modification date of a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql

On development server I'd like to remove unused databases. To realize that I need to know if database is still used by someone or not.

Is there a way to get last access or modification date of given database, schema or table?

Comment: All the approaches that rely on testing the operating system file modification time are wrong, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58246/7788

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it via checking last modification time of table's file.
In postgresql,every table correspond one or more os files,like this:

```
select relfilenode from pg_class where relname = 'test';
```

the relfilenode is the file name of table "test".Then you could find the file in the database's directory.

in my test environment:

```
cd /data/pgdata/base/18976

ls -l -t | head
```

the last command means listing all files ordered by last modification time.

Comment: You'll get false positives from this due to `vacuum` activity, hint-bit setting, etc.

Comment: the returned value doesn't exist in pgdata/base for me....

Answer (score 10):

There is no built-in way to do this - and [all the approaches that check the file mtime described in other answers here are wrong](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58246/7788). The only reliable option is to add triggers to every table that record a change to a single change-history table, which is horribly inefficient and can't be done retroactively.

If you only care about "database used" vs "database not used" you can potentially collect this information from the CSV-format database log files. Detecting "modified" vs "not modified" is a lot harder; consider `SELECT writes_to_some_table(...)`.

If you don't need to detect *old* activity, you can use `pg_stat_database`, which records activity *since the last stats reset*. e.g.:

```
-[ RECORD 6 ]--+------------------------------
datid          | 51160
datname        | regress
numbackends    | 0
xact_commit    | 54224
xact_rollback  | 157
blks_read      | 2591
blks_hit       | 1592931
tup_returned   | 26658392
tup_fetched    | 327541
tup_inserted   | 1664
tup_updated    | 1371
tup_deleted    | 246
conflicts      | 0
temp_files     | 0
temp_bytes     | 0
deadlocks      | 0
blk_read_time  | 0
blk_write_time | 0
stats_reset    | 2013-12-13 18:51:26.650521+08
```

so I can see that there *has* been activity on this DB since the last stats reset. However, I don't know anything about what happened before the stats reset, so if I had a DB showing zero activity since a stats reset half an hour ago, I'd know nothing useful.

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL 9.5 let us to track last modified commit.

1. Check track commit is on or off using the following query

   ```
   show track_commit_timestamp;
   ```
2. If it return "ON" go to step 3 else modify postgresql.conf

   ```
   cd /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/
   vi postgresql.conf
   ```

   Change

   ```
   track_commit_timestamp = off
   ```

   to

   ```
   track_commit_timestamp = on
   ```

   Restart the postgres / system

   Repeat step 1.
3. Use the following query to track last commit

   ```
   SELECT pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin), * FROM  YOUR_TABLE_NAME;

   SELECT pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin), * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_NAME=VALUE;
   ```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to reboot the system; `sudo service postgresql restart` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

My way to get the modification date of my tables:

Python Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION py_get_file_modification_timestamp(afilename text)
  RETURNS timestamp without time zone AS
$BODY$
    import os
    import datetime
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(afilename))
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT
    schemaname,
    tablename,
    py_get_file_modification_timestamp('*postgresql_data_dir*/*tablespace_folder*/'||relfilenode)
FROM
    pg_class
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_tables ON (tablename = relname)
WHERE
    schemaname = 'public'
```

I'm not sure if things like vacuum can mess this aproach, but in my tests it's a pretty acurrate way to get tables that are no longer used, at least, on INSERT/UPDATE operations.

Comment: This is wrong for the reasons given in the linked post in my comment on the main question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should activate some log options. You can get information about logging on postgreSQL [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html).

Comment: I was hoping that there's way to do it with psql. However, your tip can be also used in scripts. If everything else fails I will use log files. Thanks!

Comment: Logs won't show things like a table modified via a `select` from a function. It sounds like that'll be OK for this use case, but it won't work for people looking for actual modification times.