# How to get last access date for a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a development server that is getting crowded.

I would like to see what date the databases have been accessed to determine what ones can be deleted. Is there a way to do this?

The only thing I found when searching was for postgredb:

[How to get last access/modification date of a PostgreSQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211769/how-to-get-last-access-modification-date-of-a-postgresql-database)

Comment: What do you mean by "accessed"? Do you mean someone connected to the database but did nothing; someone ran a `SELECT` query; someone executed DML; someone executed DDL...? In general SQL Server doesn't log much unless about user activity unless you tell it to, but a few  things are in the system catalog (like [`sys.objects.modify_date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)). Your best solution may be just to run a trace for a while and observe typical activity. Or, since it's a development server, just set a database offline and see who complains.

Comment: What we do here is connect through a webapp which will always write data to a table, or run a query. We dont do anything other than that to a table.

Comment: Easy: take those databases you suspect of not being used anymore *offline* - and listen to who's yelling! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table that always gets values inserted you can add a trigger to the update/insert. Inside this trigger you can set the current timestamp in a dedicated database, including the name of the database from which the insert took place.

This way the only requirement of your database is that it supports triggers.