# Get database creation date on PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to get the Database creation date in POSTGRESQL.
My version is 9.3.4 running on Ubuntu 14.04.
Can I do it with a `select` statement or can I do it with access to the server?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Perhaps related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211769/how-to-get-last-access-modification-date-of-a-postgresql-database?rq=1 ?

Comment: Maybe something like this can get it? http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.63.0603301925130.13116@linux.site and http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-get-database-creation-time-in.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no built-in record of the PostgreSQL database creation time in the system. All approaches that rely on file system creation/modification times can produce wrong answers.

For example, if you `pg_basebackup` a replica node then fail over to it, the creation time will appear to be the time the replica was created. `pg_basebackup` doesn't preserve file creation/modification times because they're generally not considered relevant for operation of the database system.

The only reliable way to get the database creation time is to create a 1-row table with the creation time in it when you create the database, then set permissions / add a trigger so it rejects updates.

If you don't mind the risk of a wrong answer where the creation time is reported as being much newer than it really was, you can look at the timestamp of the `base/[dboid]/PG_VERSION` file. @Bob [showed a useful way to do that](http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-get-database-creation-time-in.html).

Answer (score 66):

I completely agree with Craig Ringer (excellent answer!)... but for my purposes , this is good enough:

```
SELECT (pg_stat_file('base/'||oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification, datname FROM pg_database;
```

Simple and clean (but superuser).

Comment: this is modification date on database or it can treat as creation date too?

Comment: According the documentation: "pg_stat_file returns a record containing the file size, last accessed time stamp, last modified time stamp, last file status change time stamp (Unix platforms only), file creation time stamp (Windows only), and a boolean indicating if it is a directory. "  .... so only if you are in a Windows enviroment you can use the "creation" attribute.  In my linux machine the "modification" attribute is good enough to get a pseudo creation date.

Answer (score 2):

Also alternative solution:

1. Find database OID:

> ```
> postgres=# select oid,datname from pg_database where datname='bars_paidserv';
> -[ RECORD 1 ]----------
> oid     | 5137290
> datname | bars_paidserv
> ```

2. Go to database datatfiles (you can find your directory by executing `show data_directory`):

> cd  /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/base

3. list PG_VERSION file in your OID:

> ```
> postgres@test-rp:~/9.6/main/base$ ls -l 5137290/PG_VERSION
> -rw------- 1 postgres postgres 4 Jan 29 12:34 5137290/PG_VERSION
> ```

i.e. my database **bars_paidserv** with OID **5137290** was created on **Jan 29**.