# Is there a way to determine creation time of a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL server with several databases on it.

Is it possible to determine when each database on a database server was created?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (pg_stat_file('base/'||oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification, datname FROM pg_database;
```

You can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806122/get-database-creation-date-on-postgresql).

Comment: I’ll try this out and see what it looks like.