# Know the creation date of a column in a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to get a created date of a column(not table) in PostgreSQL.
I haven't found any information in "information_schema.columns".
Any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

### Direct answer

Postgresql metadata does not contains creation or modification dates of DB objects.

So direct answer: it's impossible to find it from information_schema or from postgresql metadata objects.

Some limited possibilities exists to find this information from other sources.

### A. Logs

Check:

```sql
SHOW log_statement;
```

if it's not `none` - then it's possible to search in postgresql log `ALTER TABLE` command.

If logs were not recycled then you're in luck.

### B. Exploring files of database

It schould be possible to get some information exploring files of database. But requires knowledge of postgresql  [storage file layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/storage-file-layout.html).

Look for inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308875/1168212

If you don't have to filesystem and/or superuser rights - then no luck.